# Would Creating an Index speed up a query in SAS

Tags: sql, indexing, sas

I have never created an Index before but I'm thinking it may help here. I have a SAS dataset of approx. 7million records. It is a listing of employee entries along with their respective timestamps. I am identifying if there are any subsequent entries by the same user on the same day and then noting the timestamp. 
The data set (Entries) is 3 columns: Storage_ID, User_ID and EventTimestamp.
I'm thinking maybe an Index on Stoarge_ID and User_ID would help speed things along.
If they would help, how/where would I need to go about creating the index?

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE sub_ENTRIES AS
SELECT A.*,
(SELECT
MIN(B.EVENTTIMESTAMP)

FROM 
ENTRIES B
WHERE 
A.STORAGE_ID=B.STORAGE_ID
AND A.USER_ID=B.USER_ID
AND DATEPART(A.EVENTTIMESTAMP)=DATEPART(B.EVENTTIMESTAMP)
AND B.EVENTTIMESTAMP > A.EVENTTIMESTAMP
) AS NEXT_ACCESS FORMAT=DATETIME27.6

FROM
ENTRIES A
;
```

Comment: BTW: `... MIN(B.EVENTTIMESTAMP) ...  AND B.EVENTTIMESTAMP > A.EVENTTIMESTAMP ...`  It seems you want the *next* record for the group. Check out the `lead()` window function. FYI: dont overestimate SAS's PROC SQL.

Comment: Are you stuck with using SQL? This type of analysis is likely much easier in a data step. Essentially you need to see if two dates are back to back, so sorting and flagging is a simple process. Should be really quick with a data step.

Comment: @wildplasser can you please point to a reference for the `lead()` function? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: @Reeza : sort+data step+ retain (maybe lag/lead ;-) seems the way to go.

Comment: Sort, convert datetime to date only to do date analysis, and a transpose to wide format for entries.

Comment: And that may not even be necessary, depends on what this is for, because I suspect that the next steps may also be done directly in a data step, ie checking for time between entries or entries past hours or such.

Comment: SAS's implementation of SQL does not support windowing functions like lead().  They were created/defined long after PROC SQL was created.

Comment: doesn't the lag function only apply to finding the next entry though? that could work but i'm trying to find entries per storage_id and User_id so i'm not always looking for the next entry but the next entry in the storate_id by the same user_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a composite index (two or more columns) using SQL.

For example:

```
Proc SQL;
  create index STORAGE_USER on ENTRIES (storage_id, user_id);
```

The general syntax is for a index key of `n` columns is:

```
  create index <index-name>
  on <table-name>
   ( <column-name-1>,
     <column-name-2>,
     …
     <column-name-<n>>
   )
```

The index is most effective / applicable when the query select or join criteria involves all the columns of the composite key. Using `OPTION MSGLEVEL=I` to have SAS log index usage.